# PHP same name in foreach as outer scope causes overwrite

Tags: php, foreach, scope, behavior

So I was making a form today and happened to give the name of a variable the same name as a later used name in a foreach loop. To my surprise, the foreach loop's declaration overwrote the previous declaration of the variable.

To me, this seems rather strange since I expected the scope of the `as $value => $a` to limit the scope of the two variables to the `foreach` loop.

This is what happens:

```
php > $a = 5;
php > $b = array(1,2,3);
php > foreach($b as $value => $a){ echo $a; };
123
php > echo $a;
3
```

This is what I expected:

```
php > $a = 5; //define a in outer scope
php > $b = array(1,2,3);
php > foreach($b as $value => $a){ echo $a; /* This $a should be the one from the foreach declaration */ }; 
123
php > echo $a; //expecting inner scope to have gone away and left me to get the outer scoped $a
```

The same thing happens if I use `$a` as the key of `foreach` loop, more terrifying was this gem:

```
php > $a = 5;
php > $b = array(1,2,3);
php > foreach($b as $a => $b){ var_dump($b); }
int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
php > var_dump($b) // => int(3)
```

which overwrote the `$b` array in place, yet still looped over it's members.

All in all it seems a bit quirky. My question, is asking where exactly would I find the documentation/manual that specifies that this behavior is expected?

Comment: PHP's scope is at the function level. foreach() does not create a new scope. That being said, there WILL be a temporary "alias" created in the case of your second $b => $b version. That's more a side effect of php's internals than a new scope being created, however.

Comment: Scoping isn't done at the loop level at all?

Comment: No. There's 2 scopes in php. global, and local function/method.

Comment: Ah, when I read the first bit of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) it made me assume that the context it was talking about could be a loop. a little further down it states a bit more about the functions local scope.

Comment: @MarcB If you want to throw your comment into an answer I'll accept it since it's answered my curiousity about the subject.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scope in PHP is at global or function level, there is no block scope, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

Only functions create a  new scope. block scope formed by curly braces do not form a new one .In your example you are in the global scope.